# Which clustering method is the standard way to go for text analytics?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, text-mining

Assume you have lot of text sentences which may have (or not) similarities. Now you want to cluster similar sentences for finding centroids of each cluster. Which method is the prefered way for doing this kind of clustering? K-means with TF-IDF sounds promising. Nevertheless, are there more sophisticated algorithms or better ones? Data structure is tokenized and in a one-hot encoded format.

Comment: This sounds like a better question for [datascience.se], since it's about theory and technique discussion rather than specific coding. All that aside, the "preferred method" is likely going to boil down to "Whatever technique(s) work best with your data set to accomplish your goal". Gensim vectorization? Naive Bayes? Kmeans? NMF? All and more are on the table based on how broad this question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can cluster texts using different techniques. As you pointed out, K-means with TF-IDF is one of the ways to do this. Unfortunately, only using tf-idf won't be able to "detect" semantics and to project smantically similar texts near one another in the space. However, instead of using tf-idf, you can use word embeddings, such as word2vec or glove - there is a lot of information on the net about them, just google it. Have you ever heard of topic models? Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) is a topic model and it observes each document as a mixture of a small number of topics and that each word's presence is attributable to one of the document's topics (see the wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation)). So, basically, using a topic model you can also do some kind of grouping and assign similar texts (with a similar topic) to groups. I recommend you to read about topic models, since they are more common for such problems connected with text clustering.
I hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in my view, You can use LDA(latent Dirichlet allocation, it is more flexible in comparison to other clustering techniques because of having Alpha and Beta vectors that can adjust to the contribution of each topic in a document and word in a topic. It can help if the documents are not of similar length or quality.